# why does bones theme call the_excerpt function with parameters?

Tags: themes, search

I have been triying to localize a wordpress site which uses Bones as the theme.

In the theme's search.php, there is a line that goes:

```
<?php the_excerpt('<span class="read-more">' . __('Read more &raquo;', 'bonestheme') . '</span>'); ?>
```

In the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) it is said that this function does not take any parameters. So why does this theme send parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the theme. The real function does indeed not use the parameter:

```
/**
 * Display the post excerpt.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @uses apply_filters() Calls 'the_excerpt' hook on post excerpt.
 */
function the_excerpt() {
    echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt());
}
```

PHP will just ignore it, but the unnecessary gettext call should be avoided. Write a bug report.

Comment: Thank you @toscho. Maybe you can also help me with my [main problem](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99415/how-can-i-customize-the-search-results-in-bones-theme)

Comment: I wrote a bug report and here is the reply to it:

_italic_This is because Bones uses a filter on excerpts.
If you take a look at library/bones.php line 50: add_filter('excerpt_more', 'bones_excerpt_more');_italic_

Comment: @turzifer That filter will never get the extra parameter, because it is discarded by PHP. The explanation doesn’t make sense.

Comment: The conversation