# How can I customize the search results in Bones theme?

Tags: themes, search

In a site that uses Bones theme, I am trying to localize the search results page and would like to replace the "read more" text with something else. I tried editing the search.php but it is useless as the search.php [seems to have a bug](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99409/why-does-bones-theme-call-the-excerpt-function-with-parameters/99411?noredirect=1#99411) (It calls the_excerpt function with parameters while the function does not take any).

I also tried the filter hook as described in the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) but could not make it work, perhaps because I could not call the new function as required.

I am quite new to wordpress and php, yes, but I feel there should be an easier way to replace that text. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Filter `'the_excerpt'` on the search page only:

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse_99415_search_excerpt' );

function wpse_99415_search_excerpt( $excerpt )
{
    if ( ! is_search() )
        return $excerpt;

    global $post;

    // create a custom excerpt

    return $custom_excerpt;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that. What goes where?

Comment: Add the code to your child theme’s `functions.php` or to a [custom plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).

Comment: Yes, and then how do I call that?

Comment: `add_filter( 'the_excerpt' )` will be used on all excerpts automatically then.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that theme is wrong. I just installed it myself. The excerpt() takes no parameters according to the codex.

Other alternatives are:

1. Add the link your self.

   < a href =" < ?php the_permalink();" >My text here< /a>
2. Switch from using the excerpt function to the content() function.

   < ?php the_content("My Text Here"); ?>

If you use the_content function in your posts, you will need to add the "Insert More Tag" in your post content.

[image]